# ant deploy error - Maximum size of request reached

Tags: apex, deployment, metadata-api, ant, migration-tool

I used to deploy metadata using ant migration tool successfully but from last night I am getting the below error:

```
John@John:~/mm_workspace/TEST_Project/deploy$ ant deployUnpackaged 
Buildfile: /home/john/mm_workspace/TEST_Project/deploy/build.xml

deployUnpackaged:

BUILD FAILED
/home/john/mm_workspace/TEST_Project/deploy/build.xml:72: Failed to submit request to https://cs19.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/35.0/00D293456000Qaf for user john@test.com.dev.
Error: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Client - Maximum size of request reached. Maximum size of request is 52428800 bytes.

Total time: 2 minutes 10 seconds
```

I think this is because of too much metadata that I am trying to deploy. For now, I am deploying classes and then VF pages and so on but I am looking for an option to deploy everything in one go without running into the above error.

I am sure that people are working on more complex projects than mine with lots of metadata and I am wondering how are they deploying with out hitting this error?

Thanks

Comment: FYI..... https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_metadata.htm try retrieving the same `package.xml` from source org instead of deploying to check whether it's the error on metadata files size. Just a thought....

Comment: @sam_s, Thanks for your comment. My payload size is just 50MB but I am still getting this error. I am going to open a case with salesforce support and I will update this post once I hear from those guys. Thanks!

Comment: I opened case with salesforce support and they said the maximum payload using metadata api is 50MB and they said they are going to update the docs. Looks like they did not update the documentation yet and I did not follow up with them after that. Anyway I was able to use the approach mentioned in this  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112642/how-to-keep-sandbox-in-sync-with-changes-from-other-developers?lq=1 and for now it works!

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of limits around the Salesforce Metadata API, as we have found working on [Gearset](http://gearset.com) which allows you to manage your releases, and is built on top of the Metadata API.

Is your `package.xml` specifying everything individually, or are you wilcarding some things?

Comment: I am using wildcard for apex class and VF pages but for everything else we are specifying the names of the components. Another thing is we have lot of custom objects(around 20) but we are still in the begining stage and our metadata size continues to grow as we make enhancements.

Comment: That is still really small, we regularly handle much larger requests than that. How big is the actual metadata that you are uploading? Is it anywhere near 50meg?

Comment: Classes folder size is 47M and staticresources folder size is 9.7M