# Not able to just deploy classes folder using Force Migration Tool

Tags: apex, metadata-api, ant, migration-tool

I am trying to deploy just `classes` folder as I am not able to deploy entire `src` folder because of size issue as mentioned in this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108856/ant-deploy-error-maximum-size-of-request-reached)

Here is the task I added in my `build.xml`:

```
<target name="deployClasses">
  <sf:deploy username="${SFDC.username}" password="${SFDC.password}" 
             sessionId="${SFDC.sessionId}" serverurl="${SFDC.serverurl}" 
             maxPoll="600" deployRoot="../src/classes" rollbackOnError="true" 
             allowMissingFiles="true" pollWaitMillis="30000"/>
</target>
```

and here is the log when I run `ant deployClasses` from command prompt:

```
john@john:~/mm_workspace/my_SFDC_Project/ant_deploy$ ant deployClasses 
Buildfile: /home/john/mm_workspace/my_SFDC_Project/ant_deploy/build.xml

    deployClasses:
    [sf:deploy] Request for a deploy submitted successfully.
    [sf:deploy] Request ID for the current deploy task: 0Af29000001K8MECA0
    [sf:deploy] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
    [sf:deploy] Request Status: Pending
    [sf:deploy] Request Status: Succeeded
    [sf:deploy] *********** DEPLOYMENT SUCCEEDED ***********
    [sf:deploy] Finished request 0Af29000001K8MECA0 successfully.

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
    Total time: 1 minute 28 seconds
```

Log shows everything deployed successfully but in the below screenshot it shows zero:

[image]

Also here is my `package.xml` contents present inside the `src/classes` directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>31.0</version>
</Package>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my directory structure as requested in the comments:

```
john@john:~/mm_workspace/my_SFDC_Project$ tree -R
.
├── ant_deploy
│   ├── build.properties
│   ├── build.xml
├── salesforce.schema
└── src
    ├── classes
    │   ├── some_class.cls
    │   ├── some_class.cls-meta.xml
    │   └── package.xml
    ├── objects
    ├── package.xml
    └── pages
        ├── some_page.page
        └── some_page.page-meta.xml
```

Could somebody please help me on what is wrong I am doing here? Thanks!

Comment: It's probably a combination of `allowMissingFiles=true`, and your specified `deployRoot`.   I don't see any `<sf:retrieve>` in the target definition that you provided. Are you sure that `../src/Classes` (which would be the path relative to the basedir specified in the ANT project definition) exists and contains the .cls and .cls-meta files?

Comment: I tried removing the `allowMissingFiles=true` and still same result. Also I ran the command `ls ../src/classes/` from the directory where I am running ant command and I do see that .cls and .cls-meta.xml files exist.

Comment: Ok, now what is the `basedir` specified in the project definition?  It might help if you edited your question to include more of your `build.xml`

Comment: You need to deploy from your /src directory, not /src/classes. ANT is treating /src/classes like your /src directory, so it is looking in /src/classes/classes for .cls files.

Comment: @frontendloader, What do you recommend to deploy just `classes` folder I don't want to deploy everything in the `src` folder because of size issues as mentioned above.

Comment: You can make an ANT task to copy your classes folder to a new parent folder, and then deploy that parent folder. https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html

Comment: @DerekF, I updated my question with the directory structure as you requested. Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: @javanoob I didn't request your dir structure (though it does help to illustrate frontendloader's comment). I was asking for additional information about your `build.xml`. In the build file, at the very top, there should be `<project name="foo" basedir="bar"` xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">. I wanted to know about `basedir="bar"`. It's now a moot point though. frontendloader correctly identified the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ANT migration tool looks for `.cls` files inside of the `classes` directory directly below the directory specified in `deployRoot`. The way your `target` is set is making ANT look in `../src/classes/classes/` for `.cls` files.

You'll want to create an [ANT copy task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) to copy your `classes` folder and `package.xml` to a different parent directory, and set the `deployRoot` to that parent directory.

Comment: Great! It is working. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: It's also probably a good idea to clean up that copied directory after the deployment with a `<delete dir="foo">` task. It also might help to delete the copy dir after a deployment failure (in case some classes need to be excluded.), but I haven't figured out how to accomplish that one yet.